# Angular json request not working

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs

I'm trying to make a ajax request to a server php but angular is sending the data as string and there is not $POST in the php (the same works just fine with jquery ajax).

```
$scope.getPhotoFromUrl = function() {
    var urlData = { url: 'http://google.com' };

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "remotecopy.php",
        data: urlData
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('http' + data.url);
    });
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a strange beast :) but i find a fix for this.

```
enter code here
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "remotecopy.php",
        data: 'url=' + urlData,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        } ...
```